# Microsoft Office VSTO Add-in and ProcessStartInfo Class

Tags: c#, vsto, processstartinfo

In `VS2019`, the following code runs `CreatePDF.exe` by taking input from `c:\myFolder\test.txt`, and creates a `PDF` file `c:\myFolder\test.pdf`. But when when I run the same code from a [Microsoft WORD VSTO add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/getting-started-programming-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019), I don't see the output `PDF` file in `c:\myFolder` folder. That means the add-in is probably creating the `pdf` file in some other directory. Which directory it may be creating that `pdf` file in?

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "CreatePDF.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = "-interaction=batchmode c:\myFolder\test.txt -output-directory=" + c:\myFolder;
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = c:\myFolder;
```

**UPDATE**

The above code is from a `VSTO` project in `VS2019`. When I run the project from `VS2019`, it successfully creates a custom `ribbon` tab along with a button inside it. When you click on that button, it successfully runs the above code and generates a pdf file `c:\myFolder\test.pdf` from the text file `c:\myFolder\test.txt`.

But after I run `Clean Solution` to remove the custom ribbon and then I deploy the project using [ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2019), the add-in ribbon gets deployed successfully and the  other buttons inside the custom ribbon tab perform their task successfully. But the button that runs the above code does not generate the pdf file `c:\myFolder\test.pdf` (unless it's creating it somewhere else).

Comment: Does the directory `c:\myFolder\` exist on the machine you are running the VSTO addin?

Comment: Set a breakpoint within your add-in code to use the VS debugger to verify that the process starts and runs

Comment: @publicwireless Code works fine inside `VS2019 VSTO Project`. I just added an **UPDATE** section.

Comment: @aduguid For an answer to your question, please see **UPDATE** section to my post that I just added.

Comment: Set breakpoint at your button handler and try attaching the VS debugger to the Excel process at run time (this is an Excel add-in, correct?) OR add code to output each environment variable at runtime https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_EnvironmentVariables

Comment: @publicwireless Interesting thought. But I am using WORD add-in. Would you know how to attach VS debugger to the WORD process?

Comment: **RESOLVED**: The whole process is using some supporting files whose `Build Action` in `VS2019` project was set as `None` and `Copy to Output Directory` was set as `Copy if newer`. That worked fine when running the project from `VS2019` but it was failing when the `add-in` was deployed on the system using `ClickOnce`. But after changing the `Build Action` to `Content` it started working on the deployed `add-in` as well. Thank you all who tried to help.